# DJANGO WEBSITE: html code cannot locate the jpg location to display within my page

Tags: python, html, django

I have made a Django website and pulled a template from w3. I am trying to replace the jpg for the header that they used with my own picture but the webpage cannot find the src for my image. My folder directory is as follows:

```
- Website
    -websiteFirst
        -blog
            -migrations
            -static (files inside)
            -templates (files inside)
            -init
            -admin
            -apps
            - rest of usual scripts for django
        -WebsiteFirst
            -init
            -settings
            -urls
            -wsgi
```

I have tried as many variations as possible of the different folders within my project folder.

This is the error code with a few different attempts:

```
[06/May/2019 16:51:04] "GET /backgroundwebsite.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2113
[06/May/2019 16:51:04] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7780
Not Found: /websiteFirst/blog/backgroundwebsite.jpg
[06/May/2019 16:51:04] "GET /websiteFirst/blog/backgroundwebsite.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2167
Not Found: /backgroundwebsite.jpg
[06/May/2019 16:51:04] "GET /backgroundwebsite.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2113



<div class="w3-padding-large" id="main">
    <!-- Header/Home -->
  <header class="w3-container w3-padding-32 w3-center w3-black" id="home">
    <h1 class="w3-jumbo"><span class="w3-hide-small"></span> Garrett Young.</h1>
    <p>Recent University Of British Columbia Graduate, Prospective Data Scientist, and DJ.</p>
    <img src="/backgroundwebsite.jpg" alt="boy" class="w3-image" width="992" height="1108">
  </header>
```

the image was displayed from a website in the template however I am trying to source it from my personal computer for now.

Comment: You should use `staticfiles`, etc. for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1):

In your `setting.py` file add the following code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: Can you just upvote my answer? It'll help others also.